# Deploying n8n to Heroku

Tags: node.js, heroku, heroku-cli

I'm having trouble deploying [n8n](https://n8n.io) to Heroku via Docker registry and cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Manually provision Postgres version 11:

```sh
heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev --version=11 -a my-app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM n8nio/n8n
```

heroku.yml:

```yaml
setup:
  #addons:
  #  - plan: heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev
  #    version: 11
  #    as: DATABASE
  config:
    SUBDOMAIN: "my-app"
    DOMAIN_NAME: "herokuapp.com"
    NODE_ENV: "production"
    TZ: "Europe/Berlin"
    GENERIC_TIMEZONE: "Europe/Berlin"
    N8N_HOST: "${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}"
    N8N_PORT: "${PORT}" #each app in heroku gets randomly assigned IP on start
    N8N_PROTOCOL: "https"
    N8N_ENCRYPTION_KEY: "mysupersecretkey"
    WEBHOOK_TUNNEL_URL: "https://${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}/"
    VUE_APP_URL_BASE_API: "https://${SUBDOMAIN}.${DOMAIN_NAME}/"
    DB_TYPE: "postgresdb"
    DB_POSTGRESDB_HOST: "dbhost"
    DB_POSTGRESDB_DATABASE: "dbname"
    DB_POSTGRESDB_PORT: 5432
    DB_POSTGRESDB_USER: "dbuser"
    DB_POSTGRESDB_PASSWORD: "dbpass"

build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
```

logs via `heroku logs --tail`:

```sh
2020-04-15T11:19:50.178271+00:00 app[web.1]: [WARN  tini (3)] Tini is not running as PID 1 and isn't registered as a child subreaper.
2020-04-15T11:19:50.178300+00:00 app[web.1]: Zombie processes will not be re-parented to Tini, so zombie reaping won't work.
2020-04-15T11:19:50.178302+00:00 app[web.1]: To fix the problem, use the -s option or set the environment variable TINI_SUBREAPER to register Tini as a child subreaper, or run Tini as PID 1.
2020-04-15T11:19:50.179480+00:00 app[web.1]: su-exec: setgroups: Operation not permitted
2020-04-15T11:24:54.478493+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=my-app.herokuapp.com request_id=myid fwd="myip" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to modify the Dockerfile and entrypoint script a bit. as mentioned by @VxJasonxV su-exec requires sudo privileges, which are not allowed on Heroku.

Here's my implementation of the container-

**Heroku yml -**

```yaml
build:
    docker:
        web: Dockerfile
```

**Dockerfile -**

```yaml
FROM node:12.16-alpine

# pass N8N_VERSION Argument while building or use default
ARG N8N_VERSION=0.62.1

# Update everything and install needed dependencies
RUN apk add --update graphicsmagick tzdata

# Set a custom user to not have n8n run as root
USER root

# Install n8n and the also temporary all the packages
# it needs to build it correctly.
RUN apk --update add --virtual build-dependencies python build-base && \
    npm_config_user=root npm install -g n8n@${N8N_VERSION} && \
    apk del build-dependencies

# Specifying work directory
WORKDIR /data

# copy start script to container
COPY ./start.sh /

# make the script executable
RUN chmod +x /start.sh

# define execution entrypoint
ENTRYPOINT ["/start.sh"]
```

**Entrypoint Script**

```sh
#!/bin/sh

# check if port variable is set or go with default
if [ -z ${PORT+x} ]; then echo "PORT variable not defined, leaving N8N to default port."; else export N8N_PORT=$PORT; echo "N8N will start on '$PORT'"; fi

# kickstart nodemation
n8n
```

I have created a Github repo for the same, please have a look, I have added a well descriptive Readme file, hope it helps.
https://github.com/sarveshpro/n8n-heroku

Answer (score 2):

That `su-exec` error sounds like n8n requires root/elevated privileges, which you do not get on Heroku. If you have to configure it in some way to run strictly “unprivileged”, do that.

Answer (score 1):

Guys the easiest way to deploy n8n on Heroku is to go here:

https://github.com/UnlyEd/n8n-heroku-demo

It allows you to deploy just with a click on the button

[image: Deploy]